# How to import my AWS credentials for below mentioned python script to work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

but this code does not work, how to import my AWS credentials so that this will return correct output?

> **error :** botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect
>   to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.aws-east-2.amazonaws.com/"

***expected output :***
list of buckets in my aws account.

Comment: Do you get an error? Could you include it in your question? Also, what output do you expect?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve the "minimal" you did, but the "complete" is lacking :P

Comment: yes I am getting error...
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.aws-east-2.amazonaws.com/"

I am expecting list of buckets in my aws account.

Comment: Kindly post the error you receive in the question so that people can understand the problem that you are facing.

Comment: Have you created the `~/.aws/credentials` and/or `~/.aws/config` files? If so, could you please share the region you have set in them. This error indicates that you have defined your region as `aws-east-2`; which is incorrect. The correct region name is: `us-east-2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error received was because the boto aws client could not find the regional endpoint to call since the region was not configured for the client.

Boto searches these places for it and the credentials.

1. Passing credentials as parameters in the boto.client() method
2. Passing credentials as parameters when creating a Session object
3. Environment variables
4. Shared credential file (~/.aws/credentials)
5. AWS config file (~/.aws/config)
6. Assume Role provider
7. Boto2 config file (/etc/boto.cfg and ~/.boto)
8. Instance metadata service on an Amazon EC2 instance that has an IAM role configured.

If this python code is running on an EC2, the best practice is setup an [IAM role for the EC2 instance to assume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html). In the IAM role would be an IAM policy that allows access to the whatever you need. Then those credentials would be accessible to python in the instance metadata (8).

If needed for local development, the next best is use [Session Token Service, STS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html), to grab temporary credentials and test the code locally.

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/index.html#general-feature-guides

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your instance is not able to connect to s3 service. Run **aws configure** command to configure your AWS Access Key ID and  secret access key to access S3. It will also prompt for region name in AWS , ensure that you are giving correct region code.

Code    Name
us-east-1

US East (N. Virginia)

us-east-2

US East (Ohio)

us-west-1

US West (N. California)

us-west-2

US West (Oregon)

ca-central-1

Canada (Central)

eu-central-1

EU (Frankfurt)

eu-west-1

EU (Ireland)

eu-west-2

EU (London)

eu-west-3

EU (Paris)

ap-northeast-1

Asia Pacific (Tokyo)

ap-northeast-2

Asia Pacific (Seoul)

ap-northeast-3

Asia Pacific (Osaka-Local)

ap-southeast-1

Asia Pacific (Singapore)

ap-southeast-2

Asia Pacific (Sydney)

ap-south-1

Asia Pacific (Mumbai)

sa-east-1

South America (São Paulo)

For details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html

Answer (score 0):

Install the AWS Command Line Interface using following commands. For more details refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-bundle.html) document.

```
curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
unzip awscli-bundle.zip
sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Create an [IAM](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#home) user if there isn't one already. Refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/managing-aws-access-keys.html) document for more details.
    Download credentials file `credentials.csv`. Access Key Id and Secret Access Key will be listed in this file.
 Configure aws using following command:

```
aws configure
```

Enter `AWS Access Key ID, AWS Secret Access Key, Default region name and Default output format` during configuration.
Refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) document for more details.

After this your python code should give expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create boto3 [session](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session)

```
mysession = boto3.Session(
    aws_key=AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY,
    aws_secret=AWS_SERVER_SECRET_KEY,
)
s3 = mysession .resource('s3')
```

Comment: Technically you are correct, it is considered an bad security practice to hard AWS credentials in code.